# Is the curve $(\cos(t),\sin(t))$, for $t\in[0,2\pi[$, differentiable at $t=0$?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

Suppose we have the following curve:

\begin{equation}
\vec{r}(t) = (\cos(t),\sin(t)) \qquad t\in[0,2\pi[.
\end{equation}

My question is this: can we say that this function is differentiable at $t=0$?

On the one hand, it doesn't make sense to speak of differentiability at non-interior points, such as $t=0$.

On the other hand, this curve represents a circumference, and it totally makes sense, geometrically, to say that there exists a tangent line going through $(1,0)$, meaning it is diferentiable at $t=0$. Furthermore, I could just as easily have picked a different parametrization of $\vec{r}(t)$ and avoided this problem altogether.

So, what is the correct thing to say about differentiability at $t=0$?

Comment: @Balloon: I don't think that is usual. All that we can say here is that $r$ is right-differentiable at $t=0$.

Comment: When I was a student, I learnt that for $f$ defined on an interval $I$, its derivative at $x_0\in I$ is just (when it exists) $\lim_{x \in I\setminus\{x_0\}, x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$, so this indeed makes sense to talk about the derivative at a boundary point of an interval to me.

Comment: @Didier I see how that makes sense. Indeed, with that definition, we can talk about differentiability at non-interior points. In this case, when applied at $t=0$, I would say that that definition is equivalent to right-differentiability. 

However, the definition of differentiability I studied required $x_0$ to be an interior point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By (the most common) definition, differentiability is a local property at a point that requires an open neighborhood around the point, as you already pointed out.

One weaker concept would be to introduce the concept of a one-sided differential, i.e., the idea of converging differential quotients for every sequence converging to $0$ "from the right".

In the given case, you can also smoothly extend $r$ to a function $g$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ (or really any proper superset of $[0, 2\pi)$, which agrees with $f$ smoothly (all derivatives agree) on the original domain.

But technically, $r$ per se is not classically differentiable at $t=0$.

EDIT: One comment mentioned right-differentiability earlier than me!

Comment: In a purely topological sense, $[0,\varepsilon)$ ($0<\varepsilon<2\pi$) is an open neighborhood of $0$ in the topological space $[0,2\pi)$, and it makes sense to ask what is the local behaviour of $f$ at $0$

Comment: @Didier I don't know much about topology, but I think I understand your idea. We could say, at least looking at the circumference, that $]2\pi-\epsilon,2\pi[$ is a neighborhood at the left of $t=0$ and that $]0,\epsilon[$ is a neighborhood at the right. If we now take the left and right limits we see that they converge to the same value of $(0,1)$. In some sense, $t=0$ is not really a frontier point of $[0,2\pi[$, if we have the knowledge that the interval loops in on itself. 

But in $I\subset\mathbb{R}$, I see that we cannot say that the function is differentiable.

Comment: Of course, you can find open neighborhoods of 0 if you pick the correct topology, for instance the subspace topology inherited from ambient Euclidean space. I am, however, not aware of any purely topological definition of differentiability. (Classical) Differentiation is an inherently linear operation which requires some linear structure, which purely topological structures lack.